# Best way to write DI in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, coffeescript

The codes without inline array dependency injection looks like this

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('TripListController',
  (TripListService, $scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) ->
    return
)
.controller('UserListController',
  (UserListService, $scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) ->
    return
)
```

What I need is to inject different `TripListService` (`TripListServiceFake`, `TripListServiceDev` or `TripListServiceDist`) but keep other service such as `$scope` and `uiGmapGoogleMapApi` unchanged.

I tried to rewrite it like this:

```
useConfig = {
 fake: 
   TripListService: 'TripListServiceFake'
   UserListService: 'UserListServiceFake'
 dist:
   TripListService: 'TripListServiceDist'
   UserListService: 'UserListServiceDist'

}
angular
.module('app')
.controller('TripListController',[useConfig.fake.TripListService,
  (TripListService, $scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) ->
    return
])
.controller('UserListController',[useConfig.fake.UserListService,
  (UserListService, $scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) ->
    return
])
```

But I find this doesn't work because angularJS doesn't support partial inline array DI. Therefore, `$scope` and `uiGmapGoogleMapApi` also needs DI, though I don't want to write inline array DI for every constant service clumsily.

Moreover, I found this still looks clumsy, is there better way to refactor codes like this?

Comment: There are 4 ways to write DI, 1) Implicit annotation (without any explicit DI but not minify safe), 2) Explicit annotation with array notation, 3) Explicit annotation with $inject 4) Same as #1 but using ng-annotate library to take care of minification issue. Not sure what you are trying to do? You can look at the [angular DI](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) patterns.

Comment: have a look at the way `john papa` suggests it. just google for john papa, angularjs style guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about injecting manually with something like this?

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller((uiGmapGoogleMapApi, $scope, $injector) ->
    return $injector.invoke([useConfig.fake.TripListService,
      (TripListService) ->
         return 
    ]))
```

Of course `return`-s can be implicit.